# how to set form field value - django

Tags: django, forms

I want to show empty form field if there is nothing to show, otherwise a form field with the value inside:

```
{% if somevalue %}
  {{form.fieldname}} #<---- how do i set the `somevalue` as value of fieldname here?
{% else %}
  {{form.fieldname}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your view, if it is a class-based view, do it like so:

```
class YourView(FormView):
    form_class = YourForm

    def get_initial(self):
        # call super if needed
        return {'fieldname': somevalue}
```

If it is a generic view, or not a `FormView`, you can use:

```
form = YourForm(initial={'fieldname': somevalue})
```

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple ways to provide initial data in django form. 
At least some of them are:
1) Provide initial data as field argument.

```
class CityForm(forms.Form):
    location = ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), initial='Munchen')
```

2) Set it in the **init** method of the form:

```
class CityForm(forms.Form):
    location = ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobIndexSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'].initial = 'Munchen'
```

3) Pass a dictionary with initial values when instantiating the form:

```
#views.py
form = CityForm(initial={'location': 'Munchen'})
```

In your case, I guess something like this will work..

```
class CityForm(forms.Form):
    location = ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JobIndexSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if City.objects.all().exists():
            self.fields['location'].initial = ''
        else:
            self.field['location'].initial = City.objects.all()[:1]
```

That all is just for demonstration, you have to adapt it to your case.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Alexander's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19479547/11875147), if you wanted to **pass multiple values** to the form **during its initialization**, you can pass the data as a dictionary to your Form class constructor [(see Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

```
data = {'fieldname1': somevalue1,
        'fieldname2': somevalue2,
        'fieldname3': somevalue3}
form = YourForm(data)
```